# Dynamically Creating a Predicate with a Varying Number of Attributes and Values

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have an entity with three attributes: `studyID`:string, s`tudyName`:string and `studyDate`:date.

I need to create a predicate for searches but the user has the option to enter any possible combination of all three attributes e.g. one search is on `studyID` and `studyDate` but not `studyName` while the next search is just on `studyID`.

How to I create a predicate dynamically depending on what combination of attributes the user decides to search on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a compound predicate whose final form depends on which attributes the user searches on.

The cleanest solution is to build the predicate in code using [NSExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html), [NSComparisonPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSComparisonPredicate_Class/Reference/NSComparisonPredicate.html) and [NSCompoundPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/Reference/Reference.html). That will let you customize the predicate for each search.

Something like this:

```
-(NSPredicate *) predicateWithStudyID:(NSString *) aStudyID studyName:(NSString *) aStudyName date:(NSDate *) aDate{
  NSPredicate *p;
  NSMutableArray *preds=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
  if (aDate != nil) {
    NSExpression *dateKeyEx=[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"studyDate"];
    NSExpression *aDateEx=[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:aDate];
    NSPredicate *datePred=[NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:dateKeyEx
                                                             rightExpression:aDateEx 
                                                                    modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier
                                                                        type:NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType
                                                                     options:0];
    [preds addObject:datePred];
  }
  if (![aStudyID isEqualToString:@""]) {
    NSExpression *studyIDKeyEx=[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"studyID"];
    NSExpression *aStudyIDEx=[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:aStudyID];
    NSPredicate *studyIDPred=[NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:studyIDKeyEx
                                                                rightExpression:aStudyIDEx 
                                                                       modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier
                                                                           type:NSLikePredicateOperatorType
                                                                        options:NSCaseInsensitivePredicateOption];
    [preds addObject:studyIDPred];
  }
  if (![aStudyName isEqualToString:@""]) {
    NSExpression *studyNameKeyEx=[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"studyName"];
    NSExpression *aStudyNameEx=[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:aStudyName];
    NSPredicate *studyNamePred=[NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:studyNameKeyEx
                                                                rightExpression:aStudyNameEx 
                                                                       modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier
                                                                           type:NSLikePredicateOperatorType
                                                                        options:NSCaseInsensitivePredicateOption];
    [preds addObject:studyNamePred];
  }
  p=[NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:preds];  
  [preds release];
  return p;
}
```

Then you would use it like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  
  NSDate *firstDate=[NSDate date];
  NSDate *secondDate=[firstDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
  NSDate *thirdDate=[secondDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];

  // I use an array of dictionaries for convenience but it works
  //   for managed objects just as well. 
  NSDictionary *d1=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"abc123", @"studyID", 
                   @"firstStudy", @"studyName", 
                   firstDate, @"studyDate", 
                   nil];
  NSDictionary *d2=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"abc456", @"studyID", 
                    @"secondStudy", @"studyName", 
                    secondDate, @"studyDate", 
                    nil];
  NSDictionary *d3=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"abc789", @"studyID", 
                    @"thirdStudy", @"studyName", 
                    thirdDate, @"studyDate", 
                    nil];
  NSArray *a=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:d1,d2,d3, nil];
  NSPredicate *p=[self predicateWithStudyID:@"" studyName:@"thirdStudy" date:thirdDate];
  NSLog(@"p = %@",p);  
  NSArray *filtered=[a filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
  NSLog(@"%@",filtered);
  return YES;                           
}
```

See the [Predicate Programming Guide: Creating Predicate Directly in Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-210173)

### Update:

@DaveDelong below points out that in the first block of code above, my creation of the subpredicates is overly complex. There is no need in this case (other than execution speed) to generate the subpredicates from expressions. Instead just build the subpredicates as normal and then compound them like so:

```
-(NSPredicate *) predicateWithStudyID:(NSString *) aStudyID studyName:(NSString *) aStudyName date:(NSDate *) aDate{
  NSPredicate *p;
  NSMutableArray *preds=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
  if (aDate != nil) {
    NSPredicate *datePred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"studyDate==%@",aDate];    
    [preds addObject:datePred];
  }
  if (![aStudyID isEqualToString:@""]) {
    NSPredicate *studyIDPred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"studyID Like %@",aStudyID]; 
    [preds addObject:studyIDPred];
  }
  if (![aStudyName isEqualToString:@""]) {
    NSPredicate *studyNamePred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"studyName Like %@",aStudyName]; 
    [preds addObject:studyNamePred];
  }
  p=[NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:preds];  
  [preds release];
  return p;
}
```

Comment: While creating the `NSExpression` objects is probably *faster* at runtime, it goes create quite a bit of code to work though.  I recommend using either a predicate template (`@"keyPath = $value"`) and then substituting in values as appropriate, or just using `predicateWithFormat:` for readability.

Comment: I skipped over building the predicate in the normal fashion because the OP author requested essentially 6 different possible predicates. I don't know of an easy way to construct a predicate with a variable number of AND operators. My attempts to do so with `predicateWithFormat` failed.

Comment: right; I meant inside each of the `if()` statements, you could have constructed the subpredicates with the normal `predicateWithFormat:`, aggregated them in an array (like you do), and then combined them into an `NSCompoundPredicate` (like you do).

Comment: Oh, I see, yeah that would work. I guess I'm just to used to using NSCompoundPredicate with expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Using inspiration from this question I created my own generalized fetch for my connection manager for ease of reuse. Using a dictionary I'm able to send in key/value pairs to dynamically generate the appropriate predicate and return results without worrying about the rest each time. I hope it helps...

```
- (NSArray *)fetchObjects:(NSString *)entityName
                Parameters:(NSMutableDictionary *)parameters
{
    NSMutableArray *preds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSPredicate *pred;
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [parameters keyEnumerator];

    for(NSString *aKey in enumerator)
    {
        pred=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", aKey, [parameters objectForKey:aKey]];
        [preds addObject:pred];

        [Log LogTrace:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Query - Entity: %@ Predicate: %@ = %@", entityName, aKey, [parameters objectForKey:aKey]]];
    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity =
    [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName
                inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];


    NSPredicate *requestPreditace = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:preds];
    [request setPredicate:requestPreditace];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *array = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    [Log LogTrace:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Results count: %d", [array count]]];

    if (error)
        [Log LogError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"*** Core Data fetch ERROR: %@", [error localizedDescription]]];

    return array;
}
```